# Robot Framework - Not able to call Python function

Tags: python, robotframework

I've a Python script on the same directory that I have my robotframework script. I want to log on the console the result from a function present in my python script using robotframework.

My Python script (called raw_data.py):

```
from random import random

class raw_data:

    def return_random_number(self):
        result = random()
        return result

raw_data = raw_data()
number = raw_data.return_random_number()
print(number)
```

My RobotFramework on the same directory:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     raw_data.py

Suite Setup         Connect To Database       pymysql  ${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown      Disconnect From Database

*** Variables ***
${DBName}   #
${DBUser}   #
${DBPass}   #
${DBHost}   #
${DBPort}   #

Print random number
    ${result}=     evaluate  return_random_number()
    log  result: ${result}
```

But when I run my RobotFramework script I get:

```
Print random number                                 | FAIL |
Evaluating expression 'return_random_number()' failed: NameError: name 'return_random_number' is not defined nor importable as module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you really just need to read the error message:

```
'return_random_number' is not defined nor importable as module
```

But the question is how to go from here.

First off, it's good to start with reading the official documentation, specifically [how to create custom libraries](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) and use such keywords in your RF files.

After doing so, you'll find out several problems:

- custom libraries have a certain [scope](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope), so you should write it in there (choose the right for your case, I don't know which scope you need, so I'll randomly pick one):

```
from random import random

class RawData:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'

    def return_random_number(self):
        return random()
```

- your Python module/library won't be executed as a standalone Python script, so you can delete the last 3 lines:

```
raw_data = raw_data()
number = raw_data.return_random_number()
print(number)
```

So, your custom library should look like:

**RawData.py**

```
from random import random

class RawData:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def return_random_number(self):
        return random()
```

You can also add [library version](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-version). It's recommended, it's a good practice.

Now, you want to import your library in RF:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     RawData.py
```

I don't know why you're calling it `RawData` when in fact it returns a random number. Consider using proper names.

Then you want to call your custom keyword. Custom keywords created in custom libraries could be called by simply typing the names of the Python methods without underscores, so you don't need any `Evaluate` keyword, you can just call your custom keyword like this:

```
${result}=    Return Random Number
```